# Moving between pages and scraping as I go with Nightmare

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, promise, nightmare

There is a website that contains a page with a list of 25 entries, where each entry is a link to a page containing some information that I need. I want get to the listing page and then:
1) click on link to first entry
2) retrieve all the html
3) click back to the listing page (there is a button for this)
4) repeat for every other listing

I would also like to do this as efficiently as possible which I've been told means leveraging promises. Here's my code sketch, which doesn't work:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ openDevTools: true, show: true })
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();
var resultArr = [];

nightmare
.goto(hidTestURL)
.wait(2500)
.click('input[name="propertySearchOptions:advanced"]') //start navigating to listing page
.wait(2500)
.type('input[name="propertySearchOptions:streetName"]', 'Main')
.wait(2500)
.select('select[name="propertySearchOptions:recordsPerPage"]', '25')
.wait(2500)
.click('input[name="propertySearchOptions:search"]') //at listing page
.wait(2500)
.then(function(){
  nightmare
  .click('a[href^="Property.aspx?prop_id=228645"]') //first entry
  .evaluate(function(){ //retrieve info
    var resultArr = [];
    resultArr.push(document.querySelector('html').innerHTML);
  })
})

nightmare
.click('a[id="propertyHeading_searchResults"]') //return to listing page
.evaluate(function(){
  return resultArr.push(document.querySelector('html').innerHTML); retrieve listing page info to show that it returned.
})
.then(function (resultArr) {
  console.log('resultArr', resultArr);
  x(resultArr[1], 'body@html') //output listing page html
    .write('results.json');
})
```

This gets as far as the listing page, and then does not proceed any further. I also tried the same code, but with `return nightmare` for every use of `nightmare` except the first one. I'd seen some examples that used `return`, but when I did this, the code threw an error.

I also tried not including the third `nightmare` (the one after the blank space), and instead trying to continue the old nightmare instance by going straight to the `.click()`, but this also threw an error.

I clearly need some help with the syntax and semantics of nightmare, but there is not much documentation online besides an API listing. Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, calling Nightmare like you have it - broken into two chains - is *probably* not going to do what you want.  ([This comment thread](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/493#issuecomment-210313787) is a good - albeit long - primer.)  Memory serving, actions from the second chain will be queued immediately after the first, resulting in (probably) undesirable behavior.  You said you had it written slightly differently - I'd be curious to see it, it sounds like it may have been a little closer.

Second, you're trying to lift `resultArr` in `.evaluate()`, which isn't possible.  The function passed to `.evaluate()` is stringified and reconstituted inside of Electron - meaning that you'll lose the ambient context around the function.  [This example](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/variable-lifting.md) in [`nightmare-examples`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples) goes into a little more depth, if you're curious.

Third, and maybe this is a typo or me misunderstanding intent: your `href` selector uses the starts-with (`^=`) operator, is that intentional?  Should that be an ends-with (`$=`)?

Fourth, [looping over asynchronous operations is tricky](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md).  I get the impression that may also be a stumbling block?

With all of that in mind, let's take a look at modifying your original script.  Admittedly untested, as I don't have access to your testing URL, so this is a bit from the hip:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ openDevTools: true, show: true })
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

nightmare
.goto(hidTestURL)
.wait(2500)
.click('input[name="propertySearchOptions:advanced"]') //start navigating to listing page
.wait(2500)
.type('input[name="propertySearchOptions:streetName"]', 'Main')
.wait(2500)
.select('select[name="propertySearchOptions:recordsPerPage"]', '25')
.wait(2500)
.click('input[name="propertySearchOptions:search"]') //at listing page
.wait(2500)
.evaluate(function(){
  //using `Array.from` as the DOMList is not an array, but an array-like, sort of like `arguments`
  //planning on using `Array.map()` in a moment
  return Array.from(
    //give me all of the elements where the href contains 'Property.aspx'
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="Property.aspx"]'))
    //pull the target hrefs for those anchors
    .map(a => a.href);
})
.then(function(hrefs){
  //here, there are two options:
  //  1. you could navigate to each link, get the information you need, then navigate back, or
  //  2. you could navigate straight to each link and get the information you need.
  //I'm going to go with #1 as that's how it was in your original script.

  //here, we're going to use the vanilla JS way of executing a series of promises in a sequence.
  //for every href in hrefs,
  return hrefs.reduce(function(accumulator, href){
    //return the accumulated promise results, followed by...
    return accumulator.then(function(results){
      return nightmare
        //click on the href
        .click('a[href="'+href+'"]')
        //get the html
        .evaluate(function(){
          return document.querySelector('html').innerHTML;
        })
        //add the result to the results
        .then(function(html){
          results.push(html);
          return results;
        })
        .then(function(results){
          //click on the search result link to go back to the search result page
          return nightmare
            .click('a[id="propertyHeading_searchResults"]')
            .then(function() {
              //make sure the results are returned
              return results;
            });
        })
    });
  }, Promise.resolve([])) //kick off the reduce with a promise that resolves an empty array
})
.then(function (resultArr) {
  //if I haven't made a mistake above with the `Array.reduce`, `resultArr` should now contain all of your links' results
  console.log('resultArr', resultArr);
  x(resultArr[1], 'body@html') //output listing page html
    .write('results.json');
});
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.