# Perform click operation in succession on dynamic list of selected elements in nightmare js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, headless-browser, nightmare

I just started using **nightmare**. 
I was using it on my web page for testing purpose.

I have following user interface.

> menu
>
> tab1 | tab2 | tab3 ......(dynamically generated tabs)
>
> container div for selected tab
>
> ```
>        selected tab data
> ```

I got the dom element which contains the menu.

I don't know to how to perform click on each tab and get the selected tab data.

After reading the docs I couldn't figure out this, neither there are any example for this.

I was able to do only this -

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
  .goto('http://www.example.com')
  .wait('#menu')
  .evaluate(function () {
      var menuDiv = document.querySelector('div#menu.content-disp');
      var menuAnchors = menuDiv.querySelectorAll('a[href]');

      var res = "";
      for(var i =0;i<menuAnchors.length;i++){
          res+=menuAnchors[i].innerText;
      }

      return res;
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

I am using **nightmare** version

```
"dependencies": {
    "nightmare": "^2.8.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've built the list of anchors, you'll need to iterate over them, which with Promises is a non-trivial task.  Consider the following, which iterates over your results and gets the title for each page:

```
nightmare.then((result) => 
  result.reduce(function(accumulator, url) {
    return accumulator.then(function(results) {
      return nightmare.goto(url)
        .wait('body')
        .title()
        .then(function(result){
          results.push(result);
          return results;
        });
    });
  }, Promise.resolve([])).then(function(results){
    console.dir(results);
});
```

You may want to give ["Asynchronous Operations and Loops" at `nightmare-examples`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md) a read.  That should help you get started.

Comment: That's fantastic. Your's this answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772060/moving-between-pages-and-scraping-as-i-go-with-nightmare/38808596#38808596.
And this should be in the official read me docs on the github of nightmare -
 "Asynchronous Operations and Loops" at nightmare-examples.

Comment: @WitVault I think I'll be adding a github pages branch to Nightmare and merging most if not all of `nightmare-examples` in at some point in the near future.

Comment: It would be really helpful. Are you a contributor to nightmare js?

Comment: It's been on my mind for a couple of weeks now, and I just haven't had the chance.  And to answer your question, yes. :)